# Applying Oracle Pivot to get horizentle data

Tags: oracle, pivot

(I am new to Oracle pivot.)

The result of my code is as follow.

> ```
>  ROWNUM  C0         M               SS                                     
> ------- --- ---------- ---------- ----------                                     
>      1    a          a__               3.5                                 
>      2    a          abd               1.5                                     
>      3    a          abe               3.5                                     
>      4    a          ace               5.5                                     
>      5    b          a__                35                                     
>      6    b          abd                15                                     
>      7    b          abe                35                                     
>      8    b          ace                55
> ```
>
> Items in C0 shows vertically as expected.
>
> Now,The purpose is to show the values in C0 horizently.
>
> How to modify my code to make result as follow?
>
> ```
>   ROWNUM       M        a          b                                     
> ----------  --------- ---------- ----------                                  
>          1     a__       3.5        35                                 
>          2     abd       1.5        15                                 
>          3     abe       3.5        35                                 
>          4     ace       5.5        55
> ```

My code is as below;

```
CREATE TABLE T4 (
C0 VARCHAR2(10),
C1 VARCHAR2(10),
C2 NUMBER
);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('a','abd',1);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('a','abd',2);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('a','abe',3);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('a','abe',4);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('a','ace',5);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('a','ace',6);

INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('b','abd',10);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('b','abd',20);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('b','abe',30);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('b','abe',40);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('b','ace',50);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('b','ace',60);



SELECT ROWNUM,rr.C0,rr.M, rr.ss
FROM
(
SELECT C0,C1 M, AVG(C2) ss FROM T4  GROUP BY C0, C1
UNION
SELECT C0,SUBSTR(C1,1,1)||'__'  ,AVG(C2) ss FROM T4  GROUP BY C0,SUBSTR(C1,1,1) ) rr
ORDER BY rr.C0,rr.M ASC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the result in two ways.

Using `PIVOT` and using a traditional technique (CASE WHEN).

`PIVOT` is the recommended technique to use. But I have written both just for your reference.

**-- Using PIVOT --**

```
WITH DATAA AS (
SELECT ROWNUM,rr.C0,rr.M, rr.ss
FROM
(
SELECT C0,C1 M, AVG(C2) ss FROM T4  GROUP BY C0, C1
UNION
SELECT C0,SUBSTR(C1,1,1)||'__'  ,AVG(C2) ss FROM T4  GROUP BY C0,SUBSTR(C1,1,1) ) rr
)
-- USING PIVOT
SELECT
    ROWNUM,
    TAB.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    M,
                    C0,
                    SS
                FROM
                    DATAA
            ) PIVOT (
                SUM ( SS )
                FOR ( C0 )
                IN ( 'a' AS A, 'b' AS B )
            )
        ORDER BY
            1
    ) TAB;
```

**-- Using Traditional technique --**

```
WITH DATAA AS (
SELECT ROWNUM,rr.C0,rr.M, rr.ss
FROM
(
SELECT C0,C1 M, AVG(C2) ss FROM T4  GROUP BY C0, C1
UNION
SELECT C0,SUBSTR(C1,1,1)||'__'  ,AVG(C2) ss FROM T4  GROUP BY C0,SUBSTR(C1,1,1) ) rr
)
-- TRADITIONAL WAY
SELECT
    ROWNUM,
    M,
    A,
    B
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            M,
            MAX(CASE
                WHEN C0 = 'a' THEN SS
            END) AS A,
            MAX(CASE
                WHEN C0 = 'b' THEN SS
            END) AS B
        FROM
            DATAA
        GROUP BY
            M
        ORDER BY
            M
    );
```

**-- Output --**

[image]

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bfcdc72438be8424cfefb19c0daf91a3)

Cheers!!